# open cart- how to change type of field?

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

I want to change the type of a field(quantity) in open cart `product` table
from `INT` to `FLOAT`changed its type in `phpmyadmin` but after that when i want to edit product in panel admin , i changed the quantity to (for example) "0.5", but it was saved in database with `INT` type still!!

```
<input type="text" name="quantity" value="<?php echo $quantity; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_quantity; ?>" id="input-quantity" class="form-control" />
```

why?

Comment: i use this version of opencart::: 
 
Version 2.0.3.1

Comment: because i want to sort my product by existing to no exist

Comment: for example for "comming soon product" how can i sort it befor no-exist product??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need also modify `sql` queries, 
open:

```
admin/model/catalog/product.php
```

find :

```
(int)$data['quantity']
```

*(there are two occurrence)*

replace with:

```
(float)$data['quantity']
```

This is for admin, if you want to show it in front, modify file in `catalog` folder too.